# Java - How to access data initialize from a setter from a third class

Tags: java, oop, object, encapsulation

Main Class/GUI

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Request_DB request = new Request_DB();
        Request rq = new Request();

        System.out.println(rq.getTest());
        rq.setTest("SUCCESS");
        System.out.println(rq.getTest());
        System.out.println(request.getTest());
    }
}
```

Request.java

```
public class Request {
    protected String test = "Num";
    
    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    
    public void setTest(String s) {
        test = s;
    }
}
```

Request_DB.java

```
public class Request_DB extends Request {

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I have a problem when accessing the latest data from the setter. From Testing.java file, I call a setter to set variable "test" from num to SUCCESS. Then i call a getter form RequestDB.java to get the value of test. The problem is, i still get value num instead of SUCCESS. May i know what my problem called and a solution for it. Really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: In your code you have two objects. One that is of type `Request_DB` and the other `Request`. They are two totally separate objects, not connected in any way. `rq.getTest` returns the value from `rq` object, and `request.getTest` returns value from `request` object. You're only changing value in `rq` object, the other object remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes. This is what i mean. Thank you. Is there a way to connect those objects together.

Comment: Thank you for your points and answer. I've got the view for the solution. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the method `getTest()` in `Request_DB`, because `Request_DB` inherits from `Request` and thus can access the method `getTest()` of `Request`.

If you override the method like you did, you will access the String `test` of the `Request_DB` object which still contains "Num", because you only changed the String of the Request object "rq" and not of the Request_DB object "request".

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way for **Request_DB** to have the value **SUCCESS**, passed from the main class?

Comment: Once again, my sincere thanks. I've understand the concept and already got the answer based on your highlights. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate from Java to a real-world example.

`Request` is a class, a real world analogon might be a car model like VW Golf.

`Request_DB` is a class, a real world analogon might be a car model like VW Golf GTI. Being a subclass of `Request`, it shares most properties of its parent class (analogy: Golf GTI is a special version of Golf).

In `Request rq = new Request();` you create a new `Request` instance (buy a VW Golf). All `Request` instances come with an initial `test` value of "Num" (come with a number plate reading "GOLF").

In `Request_DB request = new Request_DB();` you create a new `Request_DB` (buy a VW Golf GTI, now you have two cars). All `Request_DB` instances come with an initial `test` value of "Num", as this is a property inherited from the parent class (come with a number plate reading "GOLF").

In `rq.setTest("SUCCESS");` you change the `test` value of this instance to be `"SUCCESS"` (change the number plate of the plain Golf to read "MY_CAR").

This analogy should explain that the number plate of the GTI still reads "GOLF" (the `request.getTest()` still returns "Num"), as you only changed the property of one instance, and are now lokking at the property value of a different instance.

Comment: Thank you. So meaning that, for me to have `Request_DB` to give value of `SUCCESS`, i need to do similar task as `Request` - `setTest` which passes the value `SUCCESS` to `Request_DB`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got the view of the problem and solution for it. Again. Thank you